# Access public variables of class in another class both are extending CI_Controller class codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, oop, inheritance

I want to access public variables of one class login without extending the other class check in codeigniter Here Variable is $fb_data in class login
Here is my code of class login

```
class Login extends CI_Controller
{

  public $fb_data;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'lib_login'));
        $this->load->model('users_model');
        if (!isset($this->fb_data['me']) ) {
          $this->fb_data = $this->lib_login->facebook();
        }                

    }
     public function facebook()
    {               
        if (isset($this->fb_data['me'])) {
            echo "<pre>";
             var_dump($this->fb_data);
            echo "</pre>";                 
            echo '<a href="'.site_url("login/destroy").'">logout</a>';
        } else {
            echo '<a href="' . $this->fb_data['loginUrl'] . '">Login</a>';
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code of class check

```
class Check extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'lib_login'));
        $this->load->model('users_model');                       
    }       
    public function index()
    {        
        if (isset($this->fb_data['me'])) {
            echo "<pre>";
             var_dump($this->fb_data);
            echo "</pre>";     
            echo '<a href="'.site_url("login/destroy").'">logout</a>';
        } else {
            echo '<a href="' . $this->fb_data['loginUrl'] . '">Login</a>';
        }
    }


}
```

but whenever i call check/index function it gives me this errore

```
Message: Undefined property: Check::$fb_da
```

Is their any way i can access the $fb_data 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First include the login.php in check.php like

```
require_once 'login.php'
```

Then create an isntance of Login

```
$login = new Login();
```

Now access fb_data

```
$login->fb_data;
```

Comment: can we access it with out including the file login.php

Comment: i have included it but it is giving me this error Message: Undefined variable: login

Comment: also it give two error 2nd is Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: create a method to access fb_data then call the method.

Comment: little bit of code will be help full because i am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

When you are making request, anything that is instantiated in that request you can use. Those things that haven't instatiated can't be used. So `Check.php` controller doesn't know what is `$fb_data` as it is calculated as local variable. If you want to have some values in `$fb_data` and get it with pseudo `$this->fb_data` it should be set in higher instance that is extended with working class. Answer is no. But you could make `APPPATH . 'core/MY_Controller.php'` and have there all code you would like to use later in `APPPATH . 'controllers/Login.php'` and/or `APPPATH . 'controllers/Check.php'` files. For that these files need to extend `MY_Controller` instead `CI_Controller`.

Comment: why MY_Controller what is it for...?

Comment: So i should create MY_Controller.php file in core folder then i need to extend the login and check classes with MY_Controller instead of CI_Controller.Am i right. and which class My_Controller extends does it extends CI_Controller....

Comment: You should check [docs and how to extend core classes](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html#extending-core-class). In that class you have to set all code you want to use later in controllers that are extending it.

Comment: is their any other way i can do this without creating files in core folder

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. It is regular/official CodeIgniter staff recommended way.

Comment: i just need the variable if $fb_data from class login to in class check.php this is what i meant is'nt their any simple way i am beginner that is why i am asking this i hope you understand...

Comment: If you are beginner, it is reason more to follow up documentation. Btw. There is no functional distinction between Login and Check controllers. You should describe what are you intending to get. Maybe your code logic should change regarding OOP MVC best practices.

Comment: is theri any chance i can create $this->ci =& get_instance(); then access it using ci

Comment: or i can access it like simple oop $login = new Login() then $login->fb_data;

Comment: Have you tried it so far? If so, you would get result or error. If you are getting an error, you post used code and error message in new question. That is way this website works. :) What are you trying to get from Login and check controllers (methods code in those are pretty much the same)?

Comment: i have done this $login = new Login(); then $login->fb_data; after including but when i access it it say  error Message: Undefined variable: login

Comment: and also Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Pretty much away from initial question. I recommend you put thoughts together, separate problems and write new question with first problem you get avoiding any other problem until first one is solved. It will speed up you getting solution. I will warmly ask you to read [this article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) that helped me and helped many to write question on right way. During reading that article you will conclude what is important  to be paid attention on and how to simplify problems to be able to start solving biggest or first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can crate a session variable such as fb_data_me and set it to 1 after logging in and set it back to 0 on logout. Since it is a session variable you can access from all your controllers.

Comment: But Here i don't need session variable i need to access it it's requirement sorry...

Comment: but variables are automatically unset after garbage collector finishes its job

Comment: is their anyother solution expect the session variable

Comment: You can store all your session data in a [database](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: it say page not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79252/discussion-between-uzumaki-ichigo-and-usama).